# delete specific objects in a list

Tags: r

`a` is a list.

```
a <- list(c(1:3),c(3:7),c(1:4))
> a
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

`b` is a series of numbers of indicators which contain some integers and integer(0).

I want to get the value of `a[-b]`, it works when `b` is an integer such as 1.

```
b <- 1
a[-b]
[[1]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

But when it comes with integer(0), the result is not what I want.

```
b <- integer(0)
a[-b]
list()
```

I expect `a[-b]` would be `a` when the `b` is integer(0), since I need to do several loops. Thank you.